# Why sometimes the moon appears to be yellow and sometimes it appears to be white?

Tags: energy, visible-light, waves

I noted that it changes depending if I'm on the countryside ( it appears to be yellow )

Comment: I've seen the Moon always yellow.

Comment: Honestly, have you done *any* research on this before asking here?

Comment: In addition to @AlfredCentauri, literally the first google reveals the mystery.

Comment: And sometimes it even appears [orange or red](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/46-our-solar-system/the-moon/observing-the-moon/142-why-are-the-moon-and-sun-sometimes-orange-or-red-beginner), as the googling also reveals.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as the reason the sky is blue and sunsets are red: air preferentially scatters blue light, letting more red light through. Whenever the moon is lower in the sky, its light has to travel through more air to reach you, which tints it yellow. You've probably noticed this effect in the countryside because there are less tall buildings, so you can see the moon when it's lower.